# Restricting parent class members to its immediate child class only

Tags: java, inheritance, access-modifiers, restriction

Suppose  I have four classes in java with given hierarchy.

```
class A {}
class B extends A {} 
class C extends B {} 
class D extends C {}
```

As per my understanding all the accessible fields of class A will be available to all its child classes through inheritance. Now what if  I want few fields of class A to be available to class B only.

Is there any way in java so that I can restrict certain fields of parent class to its immediate child class only?

Comment: If this is really what you want, then your class design is most likely wrong. What is the real use case of your question?

Comment: This was asked to me in an interview. They had given me the same scenario.

Comment: I really don't understand these kinds of questions, which have no real life value, in interviews. It really sucks

Comment: I don't know about your use case, but be aware of violations of the Liskov substitution principle

Comment: I have a feeling you'd be interested to read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) first. And then on an interview reply with mainly same line even if providing some answer via reflection in this case.

Comment: @user8001621 Wouldn't recommend taking that job. Sounds like they don't have decent design skills.

Comment: Initially I also had a same doubt about design flaw. But I wasn't sure so I couldn't take it further in interview. It was my first interview. By the way thank you all.

Answer (score 11):

Not that I would do anything like this in production, but here you go:

```
class A {
    private int a = 1;

    public int getA() {
        if (getClass().equals(A.class) || 
            getClass().getSuperclass().equals(A.class)) {
            return a;
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("hahaha");
        }
    }        

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();
        System.out.println(a.getA());
        System.out.println(b.getA());
        System.out.println(c.getA());
    }
}

class B extends A {}

class C extends B {}
```

So basically you can use this trick to allow only classes you want (using either the blacklist or whitelist approach) - to call `getA()`.

**OUTPUT:**

```
1
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: hahaha
    ...
```

Comment: **IllegalStateException: hahaha** Not that I would do anything like this in production :D

Comment: I would more likely use an `UnsupportedOperationException` rather than an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: or, more simply and precisely, `if (getClass().getSuperclass().equals(A.class))`

Comment: @Bohemian and more concise as well :) you're right of course, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> Restricting parent class members to its immediate child class only, For that,

Java provides `protected` access modifier in which, You can access class members:

**1) Within class**

**2) Within package and**

**3) Outside the package by Subclass only.**

If you want to restrict data members to the immediate child class, then What you can do is:

Declare One class as below:

```
package com.firstpackage;

Class A{
 protected int a;
}
```

Now Use the child class in another package like this:

```
package com.secondpackage;

Class B extends A{
 //Access data members of class A
}
```

Now if you declare, `Class C and D` in `package com.secondpackage;` and `extends` them from `Class B`, Then these two classes (`Class C and D`) are not the direct children of `Class A`and of course not in the same package in which `Class A` is implemented. So the data members of Class A is not accessible in `Class C and D`.

Comment: First, you need `public class A{ protected int a; }` because you need to access it from `com.secondpackage`. Then, your member `a` is `protected`, so *every* subclass can access it. So you would need to make it package private: `public class A{ int a;}`. But then `B` can't access `A.a`. Your solution will never work as is. A better solution would be to make `A` and `B` in the same package, *and then* `A.a` package private, *and then* make your package private with Java 9's modularization.

Comment: This is simply not true: having classes C and D extend B  (which, in return, extends A) in your example will still be able to access a protected field in class A - even if they're in another package!

Answer (score 2):

This is not right class design but, if you really want to do this, you can manage this scenario.

Like, you want to restrict parent class members to other than immediate child class, you can use `protected` access modifier and put other class in another `package`.

As per your example,

`Class A` and `Class B` will be in the same package and `Class C,D` will be another package. You can use protected access modifier for `Class A`'s member.

Comment: Also works to make members `private` and use `public class A { private int member; public static class B extends A { ... } }`

Comment: The comments below Ronak's answer applies here as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can set all your attributes private and access them using getters.
Then you can control the visibility and override it.

An example with 3 classes:

```
    class A{
        private String test = "Test123";
        protected String getTest(){return test;};
    }

    class B extends A{
        @Override
        protected String getTest(){return "no";};
    }

    class C extends B{
    }
```

Here the class A shares the test attributes only with B.
B can access the A attribute with `super.getTest()`
C cannot access the test.

Its a much cleaner approach than check the class type.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to achieve the purpose could be refactoring.
Defining an interface or an abstract class **Class** , implemented/subclassed by A and B, with the variables and the methods in common beetween the two classes.
 C and D extend A, inheriting the methods implemetend in A.
The choice beetween the use of interface/abstract class for **Class** is dictated from the need of reuse common fields and methods in A and B or not.[image]

Answer (score 0):

By OOPS concept:
Designed behavior of class cannot be different for one class and different for another class in inheritance concept.

To stop inheriting the fields to child class make those fields as sealed i.e. private. And if you required fields to be access by only immediate child then mark the fields as protected.

If you need access the fields till last leaf node child class (in this case till Class D) then mark the fields as public.

Or by while designing the class into the components you can restrict the inheritance of one class from another component through OOPS access modifiers at class level.